# Can pony orm infer the database structure if I pass the sqlite file?

Tags: ponyorm

What the question said.

Basically can you do something like

```
db = pony_magic(filename)
```

And get the structure in db. For example have `db.entities`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pony cannot, but [pony-inspect](https://github.com/abetkin/pony-inspect) can.